# how to handle the return value of same class in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Here's code snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
module Main
where

import           Control.Exception
import           System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World"

class IConn a where
  execute :: a -> IO ()

  delete :: a -> IO ()

data ConnA = ConnA

instance IConn ConnA where
  execute _ = putStrLn "Execute A"

  delete _ = putStrLn "Delete A"

data ConnB = ConnB

instance IConn ConnB where
  execute _ = putStrLn "Execute B"

  delete _ = putStrLn "Delete B"

class IConn (Conn b) => IBackend b where

  type Conn b :: *

  create :: b -> IO (Conn b)

  withConn :: b -> Int -> Int -> (Conn b -> IO a) -> IO a
  withConn b l u f = do
    putStrLn $ "low: " ++ show l
    putStrLn $ "up: " ++ show u
    bracket (create b) delete f

data BackendA = BackendA

data BackendB = BackendB

instance IBackend BackendA where
  type Conn BackendA = ConnA
  create _ = return ConnA

instance IBackend BackendB where
  type Conn BackendB = ConnB
  create _ = return ConnB

data Backend = forall b. IBackend b => Backend b

func :: IConn c => c -> IO ()
func c = do
  putStrLn "Beginning of func."
  execute c
  putStrLn "end of func."

createBackend :: String -> IO Backend
createBackend "A" = return $ Backend BackendA
createBackend "B" = return $ Backend BackendB

test :: String -> IO ()
test name =
  createBackend name >>= \case
  Backend imp
    -> withConn imp 10 100 func
```

If i do not wrap the `IBackend` returned by `createBackend` in data `Backend`, the `createBackend` function won't compile. But now i have to use a case statement in `test` function to unbox `IBackend` from `Backend`. It's a little cumbersome. Any suggestion to improve the `test` or `createBackend` function?

Comment: Do `createBackend` and `test` have to take a string as argument? It would be better, if possible, to make them take a singleton GADT type `SBackend b` which identifies the wanted backend, even at the type level, so that the existential wrapper `Backend` is no longer needed. This might be or not be possible depending on your use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to improve is if you make `Backend` instance of `IBackend`. Then the `test` function will be:

```
test name = do
    imp <- createBackend name
    withConn imp 10 100 func
```

Ok, let's try instantiate:

```
instance IBackend Backend where
    type Conn Backend = ?
    create (Backend imp) = create imp
    withConn (Backend imp) = withConn imp
```

But we have a problem with associated type `Conn`. One way to resolve its to make existential type for connection.

```
data WrapConn = forall c . IConn c => WrapConn c

instance IConn WrapConn where
    execute (WrapConn c) = execute c
    delete (WrapConn c) = delete c

instance IBackend Backend where
    type Conn Backend = WrapConn
    create (Backend imp) = WrapConn <$> create imp
    withConn (Backend imp) x y f = withConn imp x y (f . WrapConn)
```

---

Another way is to understand that your function `createBackend` will be updated when you add a new backend. As wrote @chi, you can replace backend name type by GADT witch will represent type of backend with parameters for construct it, like this:

```
data Backend imp where
    ImpA :: Backend BackendA
    ImpB :: Backend BackendB
    ImpC :: OptionsC -> Backend BackendB
    ...

 createBackend :: Backend imp -> IO imp
 createBackend ImpA = return BackendA
 createBackend ImpB = return BackendB
 createBackend (ImpC options) = ...
 ...

 test :: IBackend imp => Backend imp -> IO ()
 test b = do
     imp <- createBackend b
     withConn imp 10 100 func
```